# Data is not getting set in react useState hook

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-hooks, objectid

I want to set the package id in the react useState hook.
`const [packageId, setPackageId] = useState('')`

The JSX element where I am passing the ID.

```
<CTableBody>
    {packages.map((p) => (
       <CTableRow key={p._id}>
        <CTableDataCell> {p._id} </CTableDataCell>
        <CTableDataCell> {p.name} </CTableDataCell>
        <CTableDataCell>
          <Link to="/package/updatePackage" onClick={() => updatePackage(p._id)}> //This is where I am passing the id
            Update/
          </Link>
          <NavLink onClick={() => deletePackage(p._id)}>Delete</NavLink>
        </CTableDataCell>
      </CTableRow>
    ))}
 </CTableBody>
```

The updatePackage function.

```
  const updatePackage = (id) => (
    setPackageId(id) //id logs the result but packageId logs nothing here.
  )
```

When I log the `id` inside the updatePackage function it logs the result but when I try to `console.log(packageId)` then it logs nothing. I am unable to understand why this is happening.

And I want to pass this id into the another file called updatePackage screen.

Comment: Where did you log the packageId. The update will not work immediately after you've called `setPackageId`. It will work on the next render cycle.

Comment: @kitta inside of the `updatePackage` function

Comment: @JohnOliver You should see the result by adding a `useEffect` with `packageId` as dependency: `useEffect(() => console.log(packageId), [packaged]);`